# Minimising the size of the popover on iPad (CS193p 2015 lecture 15)

Tags: ipad, swift, uiview, cs193p

From CSP193p 2015, lecture 15, the following code within prepareForSegue is shown to minimize the height of a popover to just the two rows of labels and text fields on an iPad:

```
      let minimumSize = ewvc.view.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize)
      ewvc.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: Constants.EditWaypointPopoverWidth, height: minimumSize.height)
      println(minimumSize.height)
```

But in my attempts, the println shows '0.0', and the popover contains a large empty white bottom margin. It does minimise if height is hard-cored, ignoring minimumSize.height. Changing the autolayout constraints (ensuring no extra space in the bottom margin) did not work. Is there an 'on' button that I missed?!?

[Full code of view controller on GitHub](https://github.com/palewar/CS193P/blob/master/Trax%20Segue/Trax/GPXViewController.swift).

Answer (score 1):

Serendipitously, in lecture 16, Paul Hegarty refers to an autolayout constraint from the lowest text field to the bottom of the superview, which is >= standard value. A constraint to the bottom of the superview appears to be required for systemLayoutSizeFittingSize to assign a minimum height, as in the example / demo.

My mistake was to have constraints to the top and sides of the view, not to the bottom.